# How to delete particular user's chat from XMPP server in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmpp, ejabberd

I am new in iPhone Application Development. I am working on chat app in iOS using XMPP and Ejabberd. But I am not able to delete the chat of particular user (not a single message).

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self DeleteMessageChat:indexPath];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [messages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

-(void)DeleteMessageChat :(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
{
    self.cls=[self.arrProfile objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    NSString *userJid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.cls.UserId,Xmppserver];
    XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *storage = appDelegate.xmppMessageArchivingStorage;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [storage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject"
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";
    NSError *error;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt, userJid];
    request.predicate = predicate;
    NSArray *messages_new = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSManagedObject *obj=[messages_new objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    [moc deleteObject:obj];

    error = nil;
    if (![moc save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error deleting movie, %@", [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solved this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in my code. Try to edit according to you arrays.

```
NSString *userJid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",cell.frndName.text,DomainName];
        NSString *userJid1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"name"],DomainName];

        NSFetchRequest *messagesCoreD = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context=[[self appDelegate].xmppMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *messageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
          [messagesCoreD setEntity:messageEntity];
        [messagesCoreD setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID
        NSString *predicateFrmt = @"bareJidStr == %@";
        NSString *predicateFrmt1 = @"streamBareJidStr == %@";
        NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt,userJid];
        NSPredicate *predicateSSID = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFrmt1,userJid1];

        NSArray *subPredicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicateName, predicateSSID, nil];

        NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];

        messagesCoreD.predicate = orPredicate;
        NSError * error = nil;
        NSArray * messages = [context executeFetchRequest:messagesCoreD error:&error];
        //error handling goes here
         [tableView reloadData];
        for (NSManagedObject * message in messages)
        {
            [context deleteObject:message];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
        NSEntityDescription *messageEntity1 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [messagesCoreD setEntity:messageEntity1];
        [messagesCoreD setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

        messagesCoreD.predicate = orPredicate;
        NSArray * messages1 = [context executeFetchRequest:messagesCoreD error:&error];
        //error handling goes here
        [tableView reloadData];
        for (NSManagedObject * message in messages1)
        {
            [context deleteObject:message];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }

        NSError *saveError = nil;
        [context save:&saveError];
```

I added this code in `commitEditingStyle` delegate method. Here you pass friend name in userJid and logged in user name in userJid1.

Comment: Tysm. Sorry but i am not able to upvote as i have not enough reputation.

Comment: No issues, it helped. Thats enough :) hv a gud day